# How to assign return value to an object from a generic function with wildcard return type?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

This could be very basic question but I am not able to figure out this, I am trying to call a function from some library. The signature of this function is as follows.

```
<V> Channel<?,V> create(@Nonnull ChannelSetting setting);
```

I am calling this method by simply passing an object of ChannelSetting in param, And I want to assign its returned result in `Channel<String, SomeClassType>` object.  If I am doing it as follows,

```
Channel<String, SomeClassType> result = creatorObj.create(setting);
```

I a getting compilation error Type Mismatch.

> Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Channel<capture#1-of ?, Object> to Channel<String,SomeClassType>

I am not understanding how to assign return type, I can not leave <?> because I need it for specific type only.
Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to assign it to `Channel<String, SomeClassType>` (how do you want to use the result and why is it necessary)? What APIs does `Channel` have that use the first parameter?

Comment: Channel provides one function i.e produce(?, V), If am leaving channel object for wildcard then I am not able to call `channel.produce("key", SomeClassType Obj)`

Comment: Is the `Channel` class and the `create()` method part of a published library that I can look at? I don't see a way to use that in a type-safe manner, but perhaps there's some information missing. And, is the formal signature of `produce(?, V)` or is it `produce(K, V)`?

Comment: `Channel` is actually an interface while create() method returns its implementation, Library is actually internal not an open source but I can reproduce same with some simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature is telling you that `create()` returns a `Channel` where the first type variable is something you don't know. You can't safely assign it to, for example, `Channel<String, SomeClassType>` because it could in fact be a `Channel<Integer, SomeClassType>`; based on what you've shown of the API, there's no way to tell.

Comment: Is there any way I can explicitly cast ?

Comment: Sure, exactly the way you normally cast.  `(Channel<String, SomeClassType>) result`.

Comment: @MADHAVIKUMARI Yes, you can write a cast as Louis shows. But my point is that if the `Channel` implementation expects some type other than `String` for the first parameter of `produce()`, you will get a `ClassCastException` when you call it, but it will be thrown at a site where no cast appears in the source code. By using an unsafe cast like that, you are defeating the compiler's type checking.

Comment: Explicit cast works in my case, In implementation it was converting wildcard type to byte[]